# $(H,\circ)$ is a subgroup of $(G,\circ)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H \subset G$ a subset non-empty of finite cardinality of a group
>   $(G,\circ)$ such that $h_1 \circ h_2 \in H$ for each $h_1,h_2 \in H$.
>   Then $(H,\circ)$ is a subgroup of $(G,\circ)$.

In order to show that it is a group, I already know that $h \circ 1_G = h$, for $h \in H$, but I am not able to bring the $1_G$ in our subset $H$.

I don't know how to use it that our subset cardinality is finite and non-empty. Does someone could help me on this?

Comment: HINT: Taking $h\in H$, you can consider the sequence $h^n$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  Try to prove that $1 \in H$ and $h^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: How do you use this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix an element $h \in H$ (we can do this, since $H$ is non-empty). Consider the function:

$L_h: H \to H$ given by $L_h(x) = h\circ x$ (we know the image of $L_h$ is a subset of $H$ by closure).

Now $L_h$ is injective, since the multiplication in $H$ is "inherited" from $G$, and the group multiplication is injective. Since $H$ is *finite*, it follows that $L_h$ is surjective, as well-and that's all you need.

Since $L_h$ is surjective, there is some $y \in H$, with $L_h(y) = h$.

Multiplying by $h^{-1}$ (in $G$), we have:

$h^{-1}\circ(h \circ y) = h^{-1}\circ h\\(h^{-1}\circ h)\circ y = 1_G\\1_G \circ y = 1_G\\y = 1_G$

Since these are equal as elements of $G$, it follows that $1_G \in H$, as desired.